# Remove duplicate within multiple columns and keep random in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Let's assume a dataframe such as

df

```
COL1 COL2 COL3
A    1    A
A    1    B
A    3    C
B    2    D
B    2    F
```

I know how to remove duplicates row within columns COL1 and COL1 by using :

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['COL1', 'COL2'], keep='first')
```

But how could I do the same and say to keep a random row among the repeated row instead of the first ?

Comment: `df.sample(frac=1).drop_duplicates(["COL1", "COL2"])`?

Comment: @user3483203 That distracts the order in the dataframe altogether though...

Comment: @Neither it preserves the original index, so the order can be re-assembled if necessary.

Comment: What about `df.groupby(['COL1', 'COL2']).sample()`?

Comment: I don't know if its a duplicated question but @Neither should be the accepted answer